# Remove part url use nginx

Tags: nginx, single-page-application, nginx-config

I need remove part url. 
From http://example.com/backend/api/v1/some to  http://example.com/api/v1/some

There is nginx server with settings:

```
location /
{
    try_files $uri $uri/ frontend/index.html$is_args$args;
}

location /api
{
    try_files $uri $uri/ backend/public/index.php$is_args$args;
}

location /backend
{
    rewrite ^/backend/(.*)$ /$1 permanent;
}
```

but when I send POST I getting error "405 Method Not Allowed" because `rewrite ^/backend/(.*)$ /$1 permanent;` changes POST to GET.

When I set `break` as `rewrite ^/backend/(.*)$ /$1 break;` getting 404.

How make redirect from backend/api/* to api/* ?